# Чтение и вывод файлов вне директории сервера

Tags: php, nginx, apache, файловая-система, файловый-ввод-вывод

Доброго времени суток.

Мне необходимо выводить различные файлы, а именно css, js, xml, png, jpg и все другие, которые могут располагаться и использоваться на сервере.

Файлы могут находиться в папке на уровень ниже директории сервера, основная папка проекта
это `public`, веб сервер настроен на чтение `index.php` именно из этой папки.

Файлы контента при этом расположены в папке `Content`, а именно `Content\Theme\Default`, либо же и вовсе в другой папке, которая находиться на уровень ниже папки `public`.

Структура проекта приблизительно следующая:

```
web/
... public
... ... index.php
... Content
... ... Theme
... ... ... Default
... ... ... ... image.png
... ... ... ... styles.css
... ... ... ... main.js
```

Какие есть варианты "прочитать" и "скормить" браузеру файлы, которые лежат вне папки `public`?

В голову приходит лишь заставить PHP читать и запоминать файлы, после генерировать роутер с путем и названием файла, а после этого кэшированный файл отдавать по нужному роутеру с соответствующими значениями `header()`, собственно так и работает.

Но возникают другие проблемы, к примеру проблемы с памятью PHP, ведь ему придется постоянно читать, запоминать и отдавать множество данных файла. Пара мегабайт памяти будет испорчена, ко всему этому время ответа от сервера значительно увеличивается - от пары картинок переданных с помощью `readfile($png)` ответ сервера увеличился с 50mc до 2сек.

Возможно существуют различные библиотеки для PHP, которые подойдут для моих целей, либо же есть куда более простые способы подготовки файлов для браузера вне папки `public`?

P.S: Заранее благодарю ответы и любые советы.

Comment: `либо же и вовсе в другой папке, которая находиться на уровень ниже папки public` - на вашем рисунке каталогов это где?

Comment: @nörbörnën это не столь важно, написано о другой папке к примеру, это может быть `vendor` и т.д

Comment: т.е. файлы могут быть или в web/Content, или в web/public/vendor?

Comment: @nörbörnën нет, я указал, что папки ресурсов на уровень ниже папки `public`.

Comment: Замудренная структура, а деталей для ответа всё равно не хватает. Как вы ссылаетесь на файлы в HTML? Приведите пример как выглядят ссылки сейчас. Что мешает просто создать `location /content/ { root /path/to/web/Content; }` например и т.д. и ссылаться на файлы соответственно например /content/some.jpg?

Comment: @DanilaVershinin на данный момент файлы в папке `public`. О настройках сервера я не задумывался, так как их трогать не желательно.

Comment: переместить папку контента в корень сайта либо с делать символическую ссылку на нее в корне.

Comment: @teran это пожалуй самое очевидное, но папка `Content` должна быть на уровне папке `public`, в чем и заключается проблема.

Comment: так вы можете обоснуете это "должна быть" ? очевидно, это не правильное решение. Для решения проблемы, если папку  оставить надо именно там, то сделайте на нее символическую ссылку. Если например в проект подключаются плагины, которые имеют свои скрипты и т.п., то папка с плагином (вебрут плагина) именно линкуется в корень сайта.

Comment: @teran в папке `Content\Themes` могут быть различные темы между которыми пользователь будет переключаться, файлы ресурсов (.css, .js, .png и т.д) находятся в папке `Content\Themes\TemplateName\assets\*`, из-за этого нет возможности скидывать всё в `public`, можно конечно копировать файлы из `assets` папки темы в папку `public` заранее создав в ней папку с названием темы. Но выглядит это жутким костылем. Можно конечно и вовсе избавиться от папки public тогда с получением файлов проблем не будет, но откроется доступ к другим файлам включая файлы .php

Comment: выглядит жутким костылем то, что вы хотите колдовать с пхп, а линковка папки тем в корень это единственное корректное решение. Копировать их не надо, сделайте симлинки.

Comment: @teran О символических ссылках я даже не подумал, вы не представляете насколько сильно я вам благодарен. Функция ```symlink(dirname(__DIR__, 1) . '/Content', 'Content');``` решила абсолютно все проблемы. Теперь даже жалко удалять классы, которые я писал для обработки файлов ресурсов - хотя с изображениями были проблемы, так как, если в конце URL находиться .png, то сервер обрабатывал запрос как запрос к файлу и не проходит через index.php и мой роутер.

Comment: осталось только понять, а ЗАЧЕМ изначально контект ложили не в паблик, а рядом

Comment: @Ипатьев я ответил, что в папке контент есть различные темы со своими ресурсами (иконки, файлы стилей, картинки и js)

Comment: И ЧТО? Это ответ из серии "зачем мне холодильник, если я не курю?" Как наличие "различных тем" объясняет, что контент изначально не положили в паблик? А, главное, если всё равно в итоге контент линкуется внутрь паблика?

Comment: @Ипатьев от части вы правы, возможно в будущем пересмотрю структуру проекта.

Comment: "из-за этого нет возможности скидывать всё в public" - с помощью симлинка вы **уже скинули** всё в паблик. Так что советую всё-таки определиться - можно или нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. делаете ссылку(симлинк) на вашу директорию в директории public, получится примерно так: `ln -s /yourDirPath /publicDirPath`
2. осознаете, что точка входа - ваша же директория public, и строите пути к файлам исходя из этого

Comment: Да, @teran выше ответил на мой вопрос, я не задумывался о символических ссылках на папку вне папки `Public` и пытался написать некий "парсер" файлов, со стилями и JS проблем не было, а вот картинки выводились на странице без .png в конце URL, так как если добавить расширение файла (не всех файлов), то сервер пытался прочитать сам файл, которого не существует, а не следовал по роутеру.

Comment: @ZerxaFunaKaZerxa если вопрос закрыт, выставьте пожалуйста верный ответ(не хотите мой, скопируйте терана, и выставьте свой же), ок?

Comment: на самом деле меня до сих пор интересуют малозатратные по ресурсам способы доступа к определенным файлам вне папки сервера, но тем не менее - ссылка на папку на данный момент меня устраивает, возможно и вовсе более правильным решением будет перенести папку `Content` в директорию сервера `Public` . В любом случаи - спасибо :)

Comment: ну так а чем симлинк затратен то? вы фактически делаете ссылку(не копию, это важно, а ссылку). Вы точно такой же симлинк видите постоянно, когда запускаете игру по ярлыку. Ярлыков может ведь быть миллион, и все они не весят по 100 гиг(допустим, столько же весит и игра). В данном случае, когда вы делаете симлинк, и работаете с ним, вы фактически создаёте такой же ярлычок, всего то

Comment: скажу вам даже больше, я так себе подвязал рабочее окружение так, что некоторые файлы через симлинк есть у меня на рабочем столе. Я их правлю когда мне надо, а затем, с нужной директории коммичу всё в git.

Comment: касательно переноса папки, на практике было как и ассеты внутри, так и ассеты снаружи через симлинк. Тут уже на ваше усмотрение

Comment: Я вероятно не верно выразился, вероятно. Ссылка не затратна в отличие от тех костылей, которые я писал изначально. Логика была такой, что PHP читал и запоминал файл вне `Public`, а после генерировал роутер с нужным `header(content type)` и URL в виде ccылки на файл. На всё это хранилось в ОЗУ, из-за чего подобный способ довольно сильно тормозил весь скрипт, то же время ответа вырастало от пары файлов с 50 мс до 2 сек.

Comment: @ZerxaFunaKaZerxa да, это что-то не из мира сего. Подобные задачи с ассетами(js скрипты, css-ки) решаются тем, что все файлы(неважно как), в конечтном итоге оказываются в нужной коренной папке. Она открыта, и из неё все всё тянут

Answer (score 1):

давайте более детально опишем ещё этот момент:

> на самом деле меня до сих пор интересуют малозатратные по ресурсам способы доступа к определенным файлам вне папки сервера, но тем не менее - ссылка на папку на данный момент меня устраивает

итак, есть общепринятая практика хранить все ассеты(js,css) в директориях типа public (там, где в 99.9% проектов лежит единая точка входа index.php)

делается примерно следующее: вы свои файлы грузите в папки как хотите, разные фреймворки зачастую копируют свои ассеты в директорию assets, тоесть, получится `public/assets`

такой подход обеспечивает следующие преимущества:

- все ассеты лежат в доступной(и подходящей) для этого директории
- не надо шаманить с доступом, хедерами типа вашего и т.п
- если вам надо посмотреть ассет сторонней 3й библиотеки, она будет располагатъся(согласно правил выше в `public/assets/{3dlibname}/js/file.js`) например
- так же, предыдущее правило отлично работает, когда надо отладить какие-то сторонние скрипты, и не трогать при этом оригинальные

---

так же, есть подход, когда некую директорию намеренно хранят отдельно и симлинком привязывают к public. Это сделано потому что есть какие-то правила внутри компании, например, что все картинки хранятся отдельно